# In need of some advice!

Tags: advice

I am doing Mechanical Engineering (2nd year) and it's already becoming clear that I am no more interested in this course.I am very much motivated to study Theoretical Physics and Pure Mathematics(I believe this is the best thing a human can do!) but my country's education system (India) doesn't allow me to switch from engineering to any other courses(at least in my University).
Can I quit engineering,go home,spend two years studying and then apply to a Grad School?
If that is not the best strategy,I have no problems continuing engineering! 
Thank You.

Comment: Perhaps you should try posting this on the [academia](http://academia.stackexchange.com/) stack-exchange website.

Comment: That's not an entirely bad idea, and it can't hurt to try.  Keep in mind, though, that experts on mathematics are not necessarily experts on *becoming a mathematician*; that is something most would do only once. So, many of us might not have experience that sheds light on your dilemma.

Comment: At any rate, I hope you find the guidance you seek.

Comment: @AshwinGokhale In general, we like questions whose answers will help more than just one or two people.

Comment: @Omnomnomnom This question is much too localized to be well-received on Academia.SE.

Comment: Very beautiful theme xD

Comment: Up to you, I am just giving detail on everything I do personally, I think others find it interesting. I get 70 views a day on average now somehow xD

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I don't know about the educational system in India, but North American graduate schools would be very unlikely to give much consideration to someone who dropped out of university to study at home.  I would suggest that you complete your engineering degree while taking as many physics and mathematics courses as possible within that degree program.  Also, try to get in contact with someone at one of the grad schools you are interested in, to get more specific advice.

Comment: I think this is great advice. Especially agree with the suggestion to take as many mathematics course as possible while completing your degree. I myself have made the switch from an engineering degree to a masters in math and I found taking courses (with the regular lessons, homework and exams) was much more effective in my learning compared to self study